# Understanding the factors affecting wi-fi speed with the same number of antennas and posssible fastest connection controls?

Tags: router, wireless-router

I am trying to understand more on antennas, speed and the best controlled WiFi setup.
People usually say that 1x1 antennas for N router has 150M, 2x2 has 300M and so on.
But for AC router, 1x1 antennas has 433M, 2x2 has 866 and so on.

I researched quite a while but the more I read, the more confusing I feel.
I read here about 2 TP-Link routers:
One is AC5 [Archer C5](http://www.tp-link.com/en/search/?exact=1&q=Archer%20C5)
The other is AC7 [Archer C7 V2](http://www.tp-link.com/en/download/Archer-C7_V2.html)
both have 3 antennas but:
AC5 has 5G up to 867M, 2.4G up to 300M
AC7 has 5G up to 1300M, 2.4G up to 450M

Am i missing another factor about antenna numbers and speed and if a duel band antenna is faster if we allow it only to work on 5G?
Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antennas are just passive chunks of metal that are shaped to be good at letting radio waves move from air to wire and vice-versa. The antennas themselves are not what makes a given AP able to transmit more data at a time. What matters is the number of send and receive radio chains that those antennas are hooked up to, and the number of "spatial streams" that that set of radio chains is able to support.

If a box is labeled "3x3", it has 3 transmit and three receive radio chains, and may support up to 3 spatial streams. But it's not always safe to assume that a box supports as many spatial streams as it has radio chains. And it's definitely not safe to just count the dipole antennas sticking up and assume it supports that many spatial streams.

Anyway, I think you have the wrong specs on the Archer C5. It's a 2x2:2. That's why it only gets 2/3rds of the speeds that the 3x3:3 Archer C7 gets.

Also note that 802.11ac is 5GHz only. So the 2.4GHz WNICs in these APs are only 802.11n WNICs, which is why they only go up to to 300Mbps (on the 2 spatial stream model) or 450Mbps (on the 3 spatial stream model).